# Interpolation causes issues with plotting in xarray

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-xarray, cartopy

I'm trying to do some analysis of CMIP6 climate model data, and I want to produce some multi-model ensemble plots. In order to do that I need to interpolate the data to a common grid. The interpolation of the data seems to work fine, but whenever I try to plot the interpolated data it seems like there's a gap in the data at the prime meridian and at the poles. Here's a simple example where I interpolate MPI-ESM data to the grid of CESM2-WACCM:

```
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

cesm2_waccm = xr.open_dataset('pr_day_CESM2-WACCM_ssp245_r2i1p1f1_gn_20750101-20841231.nc')
mpi = xr.open_dataset('pr_day_MPI-ESM1-2-LR_ssp245_r1i1p1f1_gn_20750101-20941231.nc')

cesm2_waccm_subset = cesm2_waccm.sel(time=slice('2075-01-01', '2075-12-31')).mean(dim='time')
mpi_subset = mpi.sel(time=slice('2075-01-01', '2075-12-31')).mean(dim='time')

map_proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()

# This works.
plot = mpi_subset.pr.plot(subplot_kws={'projection': map_proj})
plot.axes.coastlines()
plt.show()

mpi_interp = mpi_subset.interp(lat=cesm2_waccm_subset['lat'], lon=cesm2_waccm_subset['lon'])

# This has a white line at prime meridian.
plot = mpi_interp.pr.plot(subplot_kws={'projection': map_proj})
plot.axes.coastlines()
plt.show()
```

As you can see, the first plot is fine:

[image: The first plot which is ok.]

And the second plot has a white line at the prime meridian and at the poles:

[image: The second plot with the artefacts.]

Is there anything I can do to get rid of that line?

Also, here are the versions of the packages I have installed which I think are relevant to this question:

```
xarray 0.20.1
cartopy 0.20.1
matplotlib 3.3.2
```

Comment: A couple of thoughts/questions. The data look like they are not wrapping and this is causing some sort of an issue. If you change the centre of the first plot to the 180 meridian, is there a gap? Are the interpolation ranges from 0 to 360? Can you make them from -180 to 180 and does that fix the problem for your display? Finally, can you do a linear interpolation along the meridian yourself to close the dataset?

Comment: @wikikikitiki Thanks for the suggestions! So, I discovered that it doesn't matter which longitude I choose as the centre of the map projection; there is always a white line along the central longitude. Also, regridding the longitudes to -180 to 180 doesn't solve the issue. I guess there's a bug in one of the packages that are used to produce the plot.

Comment: I haven't seen this myself in `cartopy` (and I do a lot of polar plots using orthographic projections). Maybe try doing without a projection (just plot lon lat on a regular grid) and if the problem persists you can probably rule out `cartopy`. I have never used `xarray` so can't suggest anything there. Good luck, and if you find a solution please let SO know.

Comment: Hi Supercell - this is definitely not expected behavior for xarray/cartopy/matplotlib - I run similar workflows frequently and haven't had this issue. Could you try to create a [minimal reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Without one it's impossible for us to debug. I expect there's probably something weird going on with your coordinates but hard to know for sure.

Comment: I opened an issue about this at the xarray GitHub repo where I got an answer to why it doesn't work: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/discussions/6010 . The problem is that xarray's built-in interpolation method doesn't know how to handle periodic coordinates. I was recommended to use xESMF instead to interpolate my data. With xESMF you can explicitly provide a flag (periodic=True) to avoid this issue.